# Strange error related to an XML file

Tags: android, button, android-layout

I'm facing a strange problem and I can't figure out why I systematically get an unexpected stop of my application when I try to inflate the following XML file in the `onCreateView` of my class which extends the `Fragment` class :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"    
    android:background="@drawable/fond_application_horizontal">

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/ZoomPlusY"
    android:layout_height="140dip"
    android:layout_width="40dip"
    android:text="Y+">            
</Button>


<Button 
    android:id="@+id/ZoomMoinsY"
    android:layout_height="140dip"
    android:layout_width="40dip"
    android:layout_below="@id/ZoomPlusY"
    android:text="Y-">            
</Button>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ZoomOptimum"
    android.layout.width="70dip"
    android.layout.height="40dip"
    android:layout_below="@id/ZoomMoinsY"
    android:text="Opt">
</Button>

</RelativeLayout>
```

If I suppress the third button, the XML file is perfectly inflated and the application doesn't crash.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance for the time you will spend trying to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably include your logcat traceback, but immediately at looking at your layout I see at least one problem:

```
android.layout.width="70dip"
android.layout.height="40dip"
```

Those property names should be `android:layout_height` and `android:layout_width`.

Also, `android:orientation` is meaningless on a `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the `dot syntax` in your third button  `android.layout.width` ? It is a copy error or this is how your XML realy looks like?